# How to download file from url and store it in aws s3 bucket?

Tags: rest, api, url, amazon-s3, storage

as stated, I'm trying to download this dataset of zip folders containing images: https://data.broadinstitute.org/bbbc/BBBC006/ and store them in an s3 bucket so I can later unzip them in the bucket, reorganize them, and pull them in smaller chunks into a vm for some computation. Problem is, I don't know how to get the data from https://data.broadinstitute.org/bbbc/BBBC006/BBBC006_v1_images_z_00.zip for example or any of the other ones, to then send it s3
this is my first time using aws or really any cloud platform so please bear with me :]

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -1):

Amazon EC2 provides a virtual computer just like a normal Linux or Windows computer.

Amazon S3 is a block storage service where you can upload/download files.

If you wish to copy files from a website to Amazon S3, you will need to write an application or script that will:

- **Download** the files from the website
- **Upload** them to Amazon S3

If you wish to do it from a script, you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Or, you could do it from a programming language, see: [SDKs and Programming Toolkits for AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/)